# Solve for $x$ where $\sin(\frac{3x}{2}) + \sin(\frac{x}{2}) = 0$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Can I ask how this equation is solved, it is visible that the result will be $k \times \pi$, but how is it solved numerically? Is the formula used for the half argument?

$\sin(\frac{3x}{2}) + \sin(\frac{x}{2}) = 0$

Comment: Do you know the formula for $\sin A + \sin B$?

Comment: If not, look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities

Comment: $\sin(\frac{3x}{2}) = - \sin(\frac{x}{2}) = 0$, $\sin(\frac{3x}{2}) = \sin(-\frac{x}{2}) $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u=e^{i\frac x2}, v=u^2$.

$$\sin(\frac{3x}{2})+\sin(\frac x2)=\frac1{2i}(u^3-u^{-3}+u-u^{-1})=0$$
$$u^6+u^4-u^2-1=v^3+v^2-v-1=(v-1)(v+1)^2=0$$

If $v=\pm1$ then $u\in\{\pm1,\pm i\}$ and $\frac x2=2\pi k+ \frac {m\pi}2$ for some integer $k$ and $m\in\{0,1,2,3\}$.  Multiplying both sides by two and defining $n=4k+m$, (which can easily shown to be able to take take any integer value), we have $x=n\pi$

Answer (score 0):

So, here we go.

Using trigonometric formula for $\sin$ we have:
$$\sin(\frac{3x}{2}) + \sin(\frac{x}{2}) = 2\cdot \sin(x)\cdot \cos(\frac{x}{2})=0 \implies \sin(x)=0 \lor \cos(\frac{x}{2})=0$$
From here:
$$\sin(x)=0 \implies x=k\pi \;\; k\in \mathbf{Z}$$
And:
$$\cos(\frac{x}{2})=0\implies x=\pi+k\pi\;\; k\in \mathbf{Z}$$
In total, we have: $$x=k\pi$$

Comment: @martin14789652: if this answer has been useful, let me know, smashing that b+1 and accepted answer buttons.

Answer (score 0):

First, take $\theta=\frac{x}{2}$

$\sin(3\theta)=-\sin\theta$

Then, we apply the [triple angle formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Triple-angle_formulae):

$3\sin\theta-4\sin^3\theta=-\sin\theta$

$2\sin\theta-4\sin^3\theta=0$

Take $y=\sin\theta$:

$4y^3-2y=0$

Trivially, $y=0$ is a solution. Dividing by $2y$ gives:

$2y^2-1=0$

$y^2=\frac{1}{2}$

$y=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}=\pm\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$

From there, you can find $\theta$ and $x$.

Answer (score 0):

From the standard trigonometric formula we have

$sin(3x/2)+sin(x/2)=2sin(x)cos(x/2)=0$. Hence, $sin(x)=0$ or $cos(x/2)=0$, which in turn implies $x=k\pi$ .

Answer (score -1):

$$\sin(\frac{3x}{2}) + \sin(\frac{x}{2}) = 0$$

$$\sin(\frac{3x}{2})  = -\sin(\frac{x}{2}) $$

$$\sin(\frac{3x}{2})  = \sin(-\frac{x}{2}) $$

$$\frac{3x}{2}  = -\frac{x}{2} + 2k\pi$$

$$\sin(\frac{3x}{2})  = \sin(-\frac{x}{2}) $$

$$\frac{3x}{2}  = -\frac{x}{2} + 2k\pi$$

$$\frac{4x}{2}  =  2k\pi$$

$$x  =  k\pi$$

or

$$\frac{3x}{2}  = \pi-(-\frac{x}{2}) + 2k\pi$$

$$x  = \pi + 2k\pi$$

$$x  =  k\pi$$

where $k\in Z$